# Time complexity of negating a CNF formula

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, boolean-algebra

Suppose i have a CNF formula. If i negate the CNF formula, then i obtain DNF formula. However, i can't find anywhere on internet that mention the time complexity. What is the time complexity of negating a CNF formula and converting it to DNF formula?

Comment: It takes linear time.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus yes it takes linear time, but i need to cite a paper that proved it takes linear time.

Comment: Can you provide an example? Negating a formula on CNF form does not produce a formula on DNF form.

Comment: There is no reason to expect this particular claim to appear anywhere. Do you need a citation for 12+34=46?

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist using de morgan law, convert all AND gate to OR gate, and convert all OR gate inside clause to AND gate, and negate all literals.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus i can't just claim something runs in polynomial time without proving that it really runs in polynomial time right ?

Comment: It depends on your audience. It would be perfectly appropriate in a computer science paper.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus so i can just say in my paper "I have not yet been able to find nor give proof that converting a negation of CNF formula to DNF formula takes linear time, however the general belief in computer science is that it takes linear time." ????

Comment: No. You should just state that it takes linear time. Only state it if you know why it is so.

Comment: With an example I meant input and output. Provide an example of what input "CNF formula" you have  and what output  "DNF formula" you wish to obtain.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist ??? i wasn't asking to obtain anything, i'm just asking the time complexity of converting a negated cnf formula to dnf formula

Comment: @LLL As said by Yuval, "it depends on your audience." It should be an easy routine exercise for an undergraduate student majoring in compute science to prove "it takes linear time to negate a CNF formula and convert it to a DNF formula". So you can, in general, just state that in a computer science paper.